# Show Lync precense indicator (with popup) in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lync

How can I add Lync indicator to my web application (intranet, all users have lync running)?

I found this link

- [involes creating a silverligh app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243697)
- [does not seem to provide popup functionality](http://htmlpresencecontrols.codeplex.com)

Any other options?

I was thinking this was pretty straight forward, just downloading some library and adding a lync class do a div with the email, but it does not look like that's the case. Maybe I'm missing something

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 0):

If you have Sharepoint rolled out anywhere in your organisation, you can use [this trick](http://geekswithblogs.net/jacobladams/archive/2011/05/03/use-hmtl-and-javascript-to-display-presence-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx) to show presence easily (by leveraging the sharepoint functionality).